# $\mu(E) = \sum_{x\in E}f(x)$ is a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set, $f: X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$. Show that $\mu(E) = \sum_{x\in E}f(x)$ is a measure on $(X, P(X))$

Comment: How is $\sum_{x \in E}$ defined?

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty direct usage of the definition of a measure.

Comment: @JonasGomes Probably good enough to define it as $$\sum_{x\in E} f(x) = \sup_{F\subseteq E}_{F\text{ finite}} \sum_{x\in F} f(x)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews if that was the case it would be plain definition

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove $\sum_{x\in E}f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)$ for $E = \cup E_n$

Comment: It doesn't seem plain to me

Comment: Yeah, countable additivity is a bit harder.

Comment: Hmmm why do you guys say it's pretty direct? Can you show me how to prove it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume $$\mu(E)=\sum_{x\in E} f(x) = \sup_{\substack{F\subseteq E\\F\text{ finite}}} \sum_{x\in F} f(x)$$

Let $E_1,E_2,\dots,$ be a countable sequence of disjoint sets, and let $E=\bigcup E_i$.

First, if $\mu(E_i)=+\infty$ for any $i$, then $\mu(E)=+\infty$. That's because if $M\subseteq N$ then $\mu(M)\leq \mu(N)$, trivially - the set of finite subsets of $M$ is contained in the finite subsets of $N$.

So we'll assume that $\mu(E_i)<+\infty$ for each $i$.

Then for any $\epsilon>0$, find finite sets $F_i\subseteq E_i$ for all $i$ so that $\sum_{x\in F_i} f(x)> \mu(E_i)-\frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$. Let $G_n=\bigcup_{i=1}^n F_i$, we have $G_n\subseteq E$ are finite and $\sum_{x\in G_n} f(x) > \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(E_i)\right)-\epsilon$. This shows that $\mu(E)\geq \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(E_i) -\epsilon$ for all $n,\epsilon$, which means that $\mu(E)\geq \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(E_i)$ for all $n$, which means that $\mu(E)\geq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(E_i)$.

I'll leave it to you to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_i)\geq \mu(E)$. That's actually the easier way.

Hint: For any $M<\mu(E)$, pick $F\subseteq E$ finite so that $\sum_{x\in F} f(x) > M.$ Show then that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(E_i)\geq M$.

Comment: Why can you always find such $F_i$?

Comment: Also, why can you make the assumption $\mu(E) = sup_{F \subset E, F finite} \sum_{x\in F} f(x)$?

Comment: For the first question, you can always find such $F_i$ by definition of $\sup$ - $\mu(E_i)$ wouldn't be the supremum of the values if you couldn't find such $F_i$.

Comment: For the second question, that "assumption" was forced on me because you didn't define $\sum_{x\in E} f(x)$. If $E$ is countable, you can just define $\sum_{x\in E} f(x)$ as a limit, but you didn't assume $E$ was countable, and in that case, you need a definition of $\sum_{x\in E} f(x)$. This particular definition works and gives you what you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks! If we only care about $\mu(E) < \infty$, can you find such $F_i$s without directly assuming this assumption, or would there be a better definition of $\sum_{x \in E}f(x)$ then?

Comment: Can you also give some hint how to show the other direction?

Comment: Hint: any finite subset of $E$ is a union of finite subsets of $E_i$. (I had a typo there in my answer, though, which I fixed.)